Changing variable names in a plot - SJplot
I am trying to change the variable names in a plot to make them more intuitive.
For example, in the replicable example below I am tryimng to change "cyl" to the "Number of cylinders"
`   data("mtcars")
library(stargazer)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars)
stargazer(fit, type = "text")

library(sjPlot)

 model.cars <- plot_model(fit, show.values = TRUE, value.offset = .3,
            dot.size = 3,
            vline.color = "#a2a4b6",
            width = 0.2)
model.cars 

`
Tried searching for solutions on R forums and could not find anything.
